# c conversion in pascal, change parameters in a filter directshow

Tags: filter, directshow, pascal

I have to convert this to free pascal for Lazarus to change parameters in a filter directshow,
i have a guide written in c.
Filters are : http://sourceforge.net/projects/videoprocessing/
I use only ScaleFilter.dll for resize my video. In [SettingsInterface.h](http://sourceforge.net/p/videoprocessing/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/videoprocessing/Source/RtvcLib/DirectShow/SettingsInterface.h) to describe how to configure the filter in application.

```
DEFINE_GUID( IID_ISettingsInterface, /* 388EEF20-40CC-4752-A0FF-66AA5C4AF8FA */
    0x388eef20, 0x40cc, 0x4752, 0xa0, 0xff, 0x66, 0xaa, 0x5c, 0x4a,
    0xf8, 0xfa);
#undef  INTERFACE
#define INTERFACE   ISettingsInterface

DECLARE_INTERFACE_( ISettingsInterface, IUnknown )
{
    /// Method to set parameter named type to value
    STDMETHOD(SetParameter)( const char* type, const char* value) = 0;
};
```

I have translated so:

```
type
  ISettingsInterface = interface(IUnknown)
    ['{388EEF20-40CC-4752-A0FF-66AA5C4AF8FA}']
  
    function SetParameter(const tipo , valore: bstr): HResult; stdcall;
    //function SetParameter(const tipo , valore: PAnsiChar): HResult; stdcall;
  end;   // bstr -> thanks to Marco Van de Voort
  ...
const 
  targetwidth  = 'targetwidth';
  targetheight = 'targetheight';
  tipowidth    = '720';
  tipoheight   = '576';
  IID_ISettingsInterface : TGUID = '{388EEF20-40CC-4752-A0FF-66AA5C4AF8FA}'; 
var 
  pSettingsInterface :ISettingsInterface;
  ...

ScaleFilter.QueryInterface(IID_ISettingsInterface, pSettingsInterface); 
hr := pSettingsInterface.SetParameter(targetwidth, tipowidth);
hr := pSettingsInterface.SetParameter(targetheight, tipoheight); 
fgRender.Play;
//*******
```

In run application :
`hr := pSettingsInterface.SetParameter(targetwidth, tipowidth);`
// ( External error SIGSEGV );

the parameters in the filter are not changed.

can anyone help me? thank you.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I use Lazarus.

Comment: What is the specific error?

Comment: Char is not a COM type, so pwidechar is more logical. Note that the COM string type is "Widestring" in fpc/delphi, but for that afaik headers list "bstr" not "char *"

Comment: thank you Marco van de Voort , I have updated my question.

Comment: __char*__ should be translated to __PAnsiChar__

Comment: I have corrected the translation in pascal with bstr or pAnsiChar. TGUID = '{388EEF20-40CC-4752-A0FF-66AA5C4AF8FA} is correct. because it does not work?

Comment: Does it return HR or it causes external exception? This seems a correct translation. Try to remove the "const" from _tipo_ and _valore_. Another thing you can try is to cast your strings explicitly to PAnsiChar. Like this: _hr := pSettingsInterface.SetParameter( PAnsiChar(targetheight), PAnsiChar(tipoheight) );_ What HR does QueryInterface return?

Comment: i use hr :=  pSettingsInterface.SetParameter(PAnsiChar(targetwidth),PAnsiChar(tipowidth)); or hr :=  pSettingsInterface.SetParameter(PAnsiChar('targetwidth'),PAnsiChar('720')); Running application, in this line of code, i receve ( External: SIGSEGV ) error. You saw the file? "SettingsInterface.h"

Comment: i use function SetParameter(const tipo, valore: bstr): HRESULT; stdcall; or function SetParameter(const tipo, valore: LPWStr): HRESULT; stdcall; in hr i receve error ( E_FAIL ), application stop in fgRender.Play; with ( External: SIGSEGV )

Comment: I was not able to solve this problem. For Anton Angelov: you know another resize filter free?

Comment: Thanks,I solved. ( The point is that if an interface has two methods (like in this case get and setparameter), and you only want to call the second (setparameter), you must nevertheless also define the first method (getparameter).
This because in normal interfaces the functions are linked to the external code based on position rather than name. ) I have
 declared GetParameter and SetParameter,  ( char* = PCHAR ). now works! thank you all and thank Marcov

Comment: Thread with solution is http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,28005.0/topicseen.html